# Stratified k-folding in trainControl in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I can see the method 'createDataPartition' can split the data based in the outcome variable:

https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html#outcome

This same applies on 'createFolds', I think.

But I'm trying to use stratified k-folding (The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class in target) when calling 'trainControl' with 'cv' method. I don't see a parameter to specify this. There is a possibility of giving the folds indexes as a parameter, but I suppose this  shouldn't work with 'repeatedcv' (as, in each repeat, it needs/creates new folds)

Does it use stratified k-folding by default? What if I need shuffle, instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution thanks my ML teacher, who led me to this answer :)

As stated here:

[Caret Package: Stratified Cross Validation in Train Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907477/caret-package-stratified-cross-validation-in-train-function)

You can use createFolds to create the indexes for folding. In case you need to use 'repeatedcv', you must create the indexes with createMultiFolds.

IMPORTANT!: Setting index in trainControl invalidates repeats/numbers arguments
https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/584